# Topic modelling: LDA returning empty topics

Tags: machine-learning, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I am running an LDA model, and when I do so the resulting model returns empty topics:

```
   Topic 1        Topic 2        Topic 3        Topic 4        Topic 5        Topic 6        Topic 7 
"character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)"  "character(0)" "character(0)" 
   Topic 8        Topic 9       Topic 10 
"character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)"
```

Here is my code:

```
library(tm)
library(topicmodels)
library(RTextTools)
library(tidytext)
library(RWeka)
#Load data
alltext=read.csv("COMMENTS_FR2016.csv",header=T,sep=';',strip.white = TRUE)

#Separate the dataset into feedback and improvements comments.
feedback=filter(alltext,alltext$CATEGORY=="FEEDBACK")
improvement=filter(alltext,alltext$CATEGORY=="IMPROVEMENT")
feedbackcomments=data.frame(feedback[,c(1,3,7)])
improvementcomments=data.frame(improvement[,c(1,3,7)])
rm(feedback)
rm(improvement)

#Cleaning the text for Improvements comments to begin with
corp_imp=Corpus(VectorSource(improvementcomments$COMMENTS))
corp_imp=tm_map(corp_imp,stripWhitespace)
corp_imp=tm_map(corp_imp,removePunctuation)
myStopWords=c(stopwords('french'),"des","une","avoir","les")
corp_imp=tm_map(corp_imp,removeWords,myStopWords)
corp_imp=tm_map(corp_imp,removeNumbers)
corp_imp=tm_map(corp_imp,tolower)
corp_imp=tm_map(corp_imp, PlainTextDocument)

#Creating a TermDocumentMatrix with Bitokenizer
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max =   2))
tdm_test=TermDocumentMatrix(corp_imp,control = list(tokenize=BigramTokenizer,weighting = weightTf))

#Now building the LDA, after identifying optimal number of topics=15
mods=LDA(tdm_test,method = "Gibbs",k=15,control=list(seed=1234))
terms(mods)
```

At this point, the object mods returns empty topics. I've tried to figure out what's wrong, but no luck. However, these steps work fine when I don't use a BigramTokenizer, but just a single word.

Any ideas would be very helpful